# Javascript to get ComboBox values works in IE11 but not in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a set of javascript functions that are working correctly in IE11 but not in Edge and I am not certain what I need to amend to sort them out. I am calling them using the Id of the select box

```
function getComboValue (combo)
{
    if (typeof (combo) == "string")
        combo = getComboById (combo);

    // If no combo can be found return undefined
    if (!combo)
        return;

    if (isDHTMLCombo (combo))
    {
        var sVal = combo.getActualValue ();
        if ((sVal != null) && (sVal != 'null'))
            return sVal;
    }
    else
    {
        var selIdx = combo.selectedIndex;
        if (selIdx > -1)
        {
            var selValue = combo.options[selIdx].value;
            return selValue;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
function getComboById (id)
{
    var combo = document.getElementById (id);

    if (combo && combo.tagName == "INPUT")
    {
        // DHTML combo is returned if the id is of a DHTML combo box.
        var par = combo.parentNode;
        if (par)
        {
            // Get the parent object
            combo = par.combo;
        }
    }

    return combo;
}

function isDHTMLCombo (combo)
{
    
    if (typeof (combo) == "string")
        combo = getComboById (combo);

    if (!combo)
        return false;

    if (combo.DOMelem_input != undefined)
    {
        // Seems to be DHTML
        return true;
    }

    if (combo.getAttribute ("igIsDHTML") != null)
    {
        // Seems to be DHTML
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I adapt these so that will return the correct information in Edge - getComboValue is returning "" at the moment

Comment: combo elements and function are not HTML / JS standard, you have to put your Edge navigator to IE mode

Comment: Are you using DHTMLX: JavaScript UI Framework? If this is the case, could you provide more related code? I can’t reproduce your issue because the html code is missing, I am not sure if it affects the test results. And if you need to get the value in the `onchange` event, you only need to define the `attachEvent`, you can refer to this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/nc6j5zwx/.